# Getting password deprecated when running az ad sp create-for-rbac --password ******

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to register a new Azure app
using azure cli , running the command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n MYAPP --password 0000000000000 --years 99 --subscription 000000-00-000-0000-00000000
```

getting warning note that says that 
Argument 'password' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

what is the alternative and how should i work with that with Python azure sdk?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that warning because for security reasons, the `--password` argument for service principal creation will be deprecated in a future release

So recommended thing to do if you're interested in using password based authentication for service principal is to let CLI generate the password for you, instead of you specifying your own, here is an example

[image]

As you can see the auto generated password is displayed as part of the response, just note that for future use wherever you need to specify clientid and password.

Here is the reference documentation from Microsoft Docs

[Password based authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#password-based-authentication)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get a password you can run this command instead

```sh
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $NAME --query password -o tsv
```

And If you would like to get objectId or appId

You could run this command

```sh
# objectId
az ad sp list --display-name $NAME --query [].objectId -o tsv

# appId
az ad sp list --display-name $NAME --query [].appId -o tsv
```